# OpenGL does not work with QT5

Tags: visual-studio, qt, opengl, visual-studio-2012, qt5

I downloaded the sample from http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/hellogl.html
When I try to compile the project in VS2012 the compiler outputs the following:

1>qtlogo.cpp(104): error C3861: 'glVertexPointer': identifier not found

1>qtlogo.cpp(105): error C3861: 'glNormalPointer': identifier not found

1>qtlogo.cpp(178): error C3861: 'glPushMatrix': identifier not found

1>qtlogo.cpp(179): error C3861: 'glMultMatrixf': identifier not found

etc.

But all is working with Qt4 in VS2010. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you get the pre-build MSVC Qt5?
If so this build has support only for OpenGL ES, as you can see in these threads: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22821
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23499
You can build your own Qt5 with legacy OpenGL support passing: -opengl desktop

Comment: Considering there are no pre-build binaries for MSVC2012 I'd say he isn't using one.